# Let $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{(1+n)}}$ then which of the following is correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{(1+n)}}$
the $a_n$ is convergent by leibniz rule for alternating series.
How can I test the convergence or divergence of $c_n$

Comment: It have been given in the picture containing the whole question..I tried but cound not solve it

Comment: **4** upvotes for a typical zero-context question? Life is sweet, sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$c_n$ diverges since $|c_n|=|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_ka_{n-k}|=|\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+k)(1+n-k)}}|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+k)(1+n-k)}}>\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}=1$.

Comment: Ok, this is confirmed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)